# How compiler identify that an exception is never thrown from the try statement body in java

Tags: java, exception

When I catch a `ParseException` (Code 1), compiler yells "`Unreachable catch block for ParseException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body`". But when I catch an `Exception`(Code 2), it is a dumbed. Why is this?

**Code 1 :**

```
try {
    int i = 0;
}catch (ParseException e1) { //Unreachable catch block for ParseException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
    e1.printStackTrace();   
}
```

**Code 2 :**

```
try {
    int i = 0;
}catch (Exception e2) { // ............. (dumbed???)
    e2.printStackTrace();   
}
```

Note : I accidently noted this in else where. Above one is just an mock example.

Comment: I'm *guessing* it has something to do with the fact `ParseException` is a checked exception, while `Exception` includes both checked and unchecked exceptions

Answer (score 8):

The reason is simple. Allocating the integer could cause a StackOverflowException, or the current thread could be interrupted (resulting in a InterruptedException). Both are subclasses of Exception, and could therefore be caught.

On the other hand a ParseException is a checked exception, which can not be thrown by your code. Thus the unreachable catch block.

[image]

Comment: ah! That hirarchy! forgot it. Thanks ruediste!

Comment: Thanks to Namalak for the hierarchy.

Comment: Actually, allocating the `i` variable cannot cause a stack overflow at that point.  The stack frame is allocated on entry to the enclosing method.  AFAIK, no exception or error is possible at that point (apart from, possibly, `ThreadDeath` ... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadDeath.html).  For the real reason, read my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is simply enforcing the JLS reachability rules for a `catch`; see [JLS §14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21).

> A catch block C is reachable iff both of the following are true:
>
> 1. Either the type of C's parameter is an unchecked exception type or Exception or a superclass of Exception, or some expression or throw statement in the try block is reachable and can throw a checked exception whose type is assignable to the type of C's parameter. (An expression is reachable iff the innermost statement containing it is reachable.)
>
>    See §15.6 for normal and abrupt completion of expressions.
> 2. There is no earlier catch block A in the try statement such that the type of C's parameter is the same as or a subclass of the type of A's parameter.

As you can see, a catch for an unchecked exception is assumed to be reachable, but a catch for a checked exception is only reachable if the `try` block directly throws it, or calls a method that throws it.

---

The rationale for the rule for unchecked exceptions is that is difficult to *specify* the situations in which an unchecked exception may or may not occur.  (In fact, it depends on the JVM implementation, among other things so you could argue that it is *impossible* to specify any more tightly than "unchecked exceptions could happen anywhere" ... which is what the current reachability rule loosely implies.)